# How to make a simple OS with very specific features

Tags: operating-system

I want to make a sort of operating system, but with some very specific features.
The only thing i need it to do is show a video, place some text over it, accept user input and some basic file manipulation.

Something that looks like an OS'es loading screen would do.

i am, however, a complete noob to this part of programming and i have no idea where to look. Don't worry i do not need a complete explaination for every single step, but it would be nice to know in what direction i should go search.

Anyone got an idea where to start searching?
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you narrowed down your specification it's still complicated enough. Playing video involves file I/O, a file system, storage device access, buffering mechanism, memory allocation, memory management primitives, GPU access. Accepting user input requires keyboard and mouse handling which requires a working USB layer. Not to mention that you needed to make the video decoding library work with your own system, unless you want to implement that from scratch too. That might require you to have an ABI or a POSIX emulation layer. You might need to port at least one or two graphics libraries like SDL.

That's why "OS loading screen"s don't play videos :)

You *might* get away with using BIOS only for accessing all devices. But BIOS and VBE are usually slow and may not work well with your video playing scenario. BIOS is slowly getting pushed out of PC ecosystem in favor of UEFI too.

If you don't need a custom OS, you can trim a Linux kernel down to the parts you need to have. Even that's not a trivial thing to do though.

Comment: Would using a linux kernel be the easiest way to do it? i already have considered it but i was hoping there maybe was another, easier way.

Comment: @AlphaXi yes i think reusing an open source kernel (Linux, *BSD etc) would be the easiest and the most compatible with hardware. hardware is hard. :)

Comment: ah okay, that saved me centuries of looking for other solutions,thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh also, do u maybe know a place i could look for such a kernel? is LinuxFromScratch a good idea to get started with?

Comment: @AlphaXi i haven't tried doing it so i wouldn't know. people in IRC channels like #linux on freenode would know better.